# tesseract lower size of pdf output file

Tags: tesseract

After the scanned images is there an option to output low resolution pdf images  and text
The images in the pdf are so huge that the size of the pdf goes upto 1 gb.

using cmd like :

```
tesseract testing/eurotext.png testing/eurotext-eng -l eng pdf
```

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775306/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-pdf-generated-by-tesseract) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract use provided image(s) for creating pdf without its modification => if your input image size is big => pdf will be big.
So you can:

1. Decrease size of input image (e.g. use tiff with g4, resize image...)
2. Use tesseract to produce hocr file and create pdf with some other tool like [hocr2pdf](http://exactcode.com/opensource/exactimage/), [hocr-pdf](https://github.com/tmbdev/hocr-tools)...)
3. Use some pdf compression tool (there are online tools and offline like [pdfsizeopt](https://github.com/ImageProcessing-ElectronicPublications/pdfsizeopt)